# Упорядоченный обход префиксного дерева

Tags: алгоритм, структуры, дерево, структуры-данных

Существует префиксное дерево (нагруженное дерево, trie).
[image: Префиксное дерево]

Дерево хранит в себе пару ключ/значение.
Необходимо реализовать упорядоченный обход дерева по значению, т.е. необходимо идти от ветвей с наибольшим значением к ветвям с наименьшим.
Поскольку первая и вторая пары результирующего набора могут быть в противоположных ветвях, то возникают сложности.

**Обновление**

Дерево никак не отсортировано. У каждого узла может быть бесконечно потомков. Думаю хранить в каждом узле максимальное значение на этой ветви. И пытаться делать прицельный обход.

Comment: Если дерево упорядочено по ключу, а обход нужно делать по значению, то боюсь без дополнительной структуры данных (например, массива, который вам придётся отсортировать) никак.

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно обходить дерево с максимального значения к минимальному я бы посоветовал использовать двоичную кучу (двоичное дерево), где значение в любой вершине всегда больше потомков.

При этом построение кучи `O(2n*log n)`, добавление элемента `O(log n)`

Comment: необходимо реализовать autocomplete, который будет выдавать окончание слова в зависимости от частоты встреч слова, которая задана в словаре.
Двоичная куча здесь не подойдёт.
Хотелось бы реализовать прицельный обход кучи, но в итоге всё сводится к тому же кэшу.

Comment: @AydarGarafutdinov почему двоичная куча не подойдет? Я так понял, что построение кучи не критично время работы алгоритма, а вот выборка первых N максимальных по времени должно быть очень быстрым

Comment: Двойная куча не подойдёт потому что поиск идёт по префиксу. То есть  у одного узла может быть бесконечное количество потомков.

Comment: Понял, тогда действительно не обойтись без дополнительной сортированной структуры данных

Comment: Точнее лично я не вижу пока другого решения. А если например на каждом уровне элементы располагать по возрастанию слева на право, а в каждом элементе хранить кол-во дочерних элементов? Тогда обход будет с сначала по всем правым ветвям

Comment: Префиксное дерево с кэшем это решение в лоб. Но после [этой книги](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1039964/) всё время кажется что есть куда проще вариант.